# How to assign a reserved IP to a classic cloud service through Portal

Tags: azure

This is an [easy task with PowerShell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/).

But since we can now create reserved IP's through the Azure Portal, is it also possible to assign it to a classic cloud service through the portal? I can't find any documentation about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't using azure portal. You can using azure powershell cmdlets.

For existing cloud service-

```
New-AzureReservedIP –ReservedIPName "MyReservedIP" –Location "YourLocation"
New-AzureReservedIP –ReservedIPName "MyReservedIP" –Location "YourLocation" -ServiceName "TestService"
```

For a new cloud service-

```
New-AzureReservedIP –ReservedIPName "MyReservedIP" –Location "Central US"
$image = Get-AzureVMImage|?{$_.ImageName -like "*RightImage-Windows-2012R2-x64*"}
New-AzureVMConfig -Name "TestVM" -InstanceSize "Small" -ImageName $image.ImageName `
| Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -Windows -AdminUsername "adminuser" -Password "MyP@ssw0rd!!" `
| New-AzureVM -ServiceName "TestService" -ReservedIPName "MyReservedIP" -Location "Central US"
```

You can refer to the standard documentaion here- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/

Comment: Note that Azure does some phenomenally stupid stuff with naming. Call "Get-AzureReservedIP" without parameters to see what the "actual" name of the reserved IP is. You can't see it through the portal.