# How to assign a reserved IP address to a cloud service on Azure using Powershell 7?

Tags: azure, powershell, networking, azure-powershell, azure-cloud-services

I have been using the `New-AzureReservedIP` cmdlet to create a new reserved IP address in Azure and associate it with an Azure cloud service staging slot. Basically what is described [in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39657576/how-to-assign-a-reserved-ip-to-a-classic-cloud-service-through-portal) This cmdlet was part of the Azure module. However, as we know the Azure and AzureRM modules are not available in PS7 anymore. And this workstep is not even available in the Azure GUI.

As [Microsoft recommends switching to PS7 and the Az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-4.5.0) I assume that there is another way there to achieve the same thing. However, so far I was unable to find a solution.

The problem is that the staging slot requires a reserved IP if the production slot has one. To limit expenses we delete our staging slots after deployment. If we'd just keep and update it, that would not be a problem. Also, I was unable to find a way to re-use an existing reserved IP (that was created with `New-AzureReservedIP`previously) for the next staging deployment, so far I always needed to create a new one using `New-AzureReservedIP`. I ended up having quite a few reserved IP addresses which I don't use anymore so I wonder if they can be recycled somehow?

What would be best practice to solve this in PS7?

Comment: Reserved IP belongs to ASM api (Classic) and will be depricated by 2023. Hence it doesnt exist in ARM. The new ARM API doesnt support this functionallity. In ARM you have the option to use static Public IP (IP owned by Microsoft) or Public IP Prefix which is when you buy the IP address/IP range.

Comment: New-AzPublicIpAddress = https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/new-azpublicipaddress?view=azps-4.5.0
and New-AzPublicIpPrefix  = https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/new-azpublicipprefix?view=azps-4.5.0

Comment: The proper approach here would be move out of classic (ASM) and move to ARM. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/migration-classic-resource-manager-faq

Comment: @DanielBjörk you may post a your comments as an answer.

Comment: @NancyXiong sure, I just wanted to see if Aileron79 wanted some more clarification before. But anyway I added an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reserved IP belongs to ASM API (Classic) and will be deprecated by 2023. Hence it doesn't exist in ARM. The new ARM API doesn't support this functionality. In ARM you have the option to use static Public IP (IP owned by Microsoft) or Public IP Prefix which is when you buy the IP address/IP range.

New-AzPublicIpAddress
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/new-azpublicipprefix?view=azps-4.5.0

New-AzPublicIpPrefix
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/new-azpublicipaddress?view=azps-4.5.0

But one thing to note is that if you are using App Service you actually get a Static Public IP for your App Service but that one is shared with many other customers hence you need to use your App Service URL eg. https://[AppServiceName].azurewebsites.net or add a Custom Domain to your App Service.

So if you really need a Public IP that is not shared you have to move over to IaaS eg. Virtual Machines

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, your comments pointed me in the right direction. I have accepted that answer even though I don't like it (which is not your fault). I did some further research, cloud services are actually not discontinued by 2023 but still there is no support for them in PS7 for the reasons you mentioned. There also is not really a replacement for them in ARM. Microsoft recommends Service Fabrics, but migration causes quite an effort. The situation is not satisfying as there does not seem to be a simple solution. I really don't like how MS deals with their architectural changes.

Comment: @Aileron79 yeah I understand your feeling. But Microsoft has been trying to move from ASM for some years already and started to discontinue stuff. May I ask what you are using Cloud Service for?

Comment: In that case it's a web service collecting large amounts of data from numerous APIs and distributing that data among local databases. Availability is an issue, so the VIP-swap feature is quite important. I am perfectly aware that there are other options to achieve the same thing, but these services are well integrated into our landscape and build pipelines. Don't get me wrong, the problem is not Microsoft discontinuing stuff but rather not providing easy migration paths and/or replacement for discontinued services one relies upon. It might be my limited knowledge about ASM/ARM talking though.

Comment: In ARM you have many different options for this. Depending on how and what its doing. Eg. you can use App Service+API Management (that is a really great solution for many things) or you can look into event grid or if its doing outbound stuff you can look into Azure Functions or Logic App. But I understand that the issue is the effort you need to put in to moving out of ASM stuff but i think that you will save time and money by doing so. :)